# PDF document converted from a MS-Word file shows jpeg as text rather than images

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, pdf-reader

I have a document in MS Word which includes tables that I want to display as images rather than text. In the document I have inputted them as jpegs which were created by selecting the table, pasting it into another document and then special pasting it back into the main document. In Word this makes the table an image where you cannot select the text.

When I convert the file into a PDF document (using either 'save as pdf file' or 'print to pdf' options) the images are text in the PDF document rather than the images I wanted.

Is there a way to get the jpegs to appear as images rather than text in the PDF file? The only way that seems to work is to copy the images again and repaste them, but the quality is then really bad.

Comment: What you are describing seems impossible: Word does not do OCR when printing to PDF.

Comment: What are you actually using to view the PDFs? Your viewer might support OCR? Why is it important that the tables are images?

Comment: Thank you for responding. When I view the Word document the tables are images. I cannot select individual text and paste it elsewhere. When I view it in  Adobe Acrobat Reader DC I can select a line of text from the table and paste it elsewhere. If it is the OCR is there a way to prevent this from happening? I have been instructed that this is how the document should be formatted. I think to ensure all viewers can save and use the individual table without issues of changes in format etc.

Comment: Please provide an example PDF that we can analyze.